# PHP $_SESSION is working but can't get $_GET to work

Tags: php, session

I'm struggling with using $_GET on my website. I have set up a login page and after logging in the user is redirected to his/her profile. I want to create a dynamic url variable. I set a session on login page and after being redirected to the profile "echo $_SESSION['username']" echoes properly. However when trying to do the same with $_GET nothing is displayed. I've checked numerous tutorials and even when I do exactly as shown I never get this to work. Here's my code:

login.php

```
 <?php 
 include ("./Various/header.php");
 require './Various/connections.php';

 if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
      session_start();

 //Set Variables
 $loginusername = $_POST['userlogin'];
 $loginpassword = $_POST['passwordlogin'];

 if(!empty($loginusername)&& !empty($loginpassword)){
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$loginusername'");
     $checkuser=mysql_num_rows($sql);

     if($checkuser == 1) {

         $passrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
         $checkpass = $passrow['password'];

         $userdb = $passrow['username'];
         $iddb = $passrow['id'];

    if ($checkpass == $loginpassword)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $loginusername;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $iddb;
        header("Location: testprofile.php?username = $loginusername");
        exit();

    }
    else {
        echo "Password is incorrect";
    }

     }
     else {
         echo "$loginusername doesn't exist";
     }
 }
 else {
     echo "Please fill out the fields";
 }

 }

?>


<div style=" width: 400px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto" class="LoginForm">
        <table class= "logintable">
             <tr><td width="60%" valign="top">
                  <h3>MySite</h3>
            <h2>Login</h2>
                 <form action="login.php" method="post">
                     <input type="text" name="userlogin" size="12" placeholder="Username"/><br/> <br/>
                <input type="password" name="passwordlogin" size="12" placeholder="Password"/><br/> <br/>
                     <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login!"/>
                     </form>
                 <div id="forgotpassword">
    <a href="#">I forgot my password</a>
    </div>   
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

            </div>
```

For the simplicity of this example I've created an almost blank profile page called testprofile.php

testprofile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_GET['username']; 
echo $_GET['id'];

?>
```

This gives me nothing. However if you do this:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['username']; 
echo $_SESSION['id'];

?>
```

You can see the logged-in user's username and id. I've tried moving the session_start() in login.php at the very top (that's how it was at the beginning) but it didn't help at all. 
I was able to set up a whole user profile page however users could not view other users' profiles. That's why I'm struggling with this now.
I hope anyone can show me that this is a really trivial error and I've plucked my hair for no reason.

Best Regards

David

---

Okay, I'm gonna paste in my code since this is getting ridiculous. I don't get this $_GET function, it seems to work elsewhere but this profile page.

login.php

```
     <?php 
 include ("./Various/header.php");
 require './Various/connections.php';

 if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
      session_start();

 //Set Variables
 $loginusername = $_POST['userlogin'];
 $loginpassword = $_POST['passwordlogin'];

 if(!empty($loginusername)&& !empty($loginpassword)){
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$loginusername'");
     $checkuser=mysql_num_rows($sql);

     if($checkuser == 1) {

         $passrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
         $checkpass = $passrow['password'];

         $userdb = $passrow['username'];
         $iddb = $passrow['id'];

    if ($checkpass == $loginpassword)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $loginusername;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $iddb;
        header("Location: profile.php");
        exit();

    }
    else {
        echo "Password is incorrect";
    }

     }
     else {
         echo "$loginusername doesn't exist";
     }
 }
 else {
     echo "Please fill out the fields";
 }

 }

?>


<div style=" width: 400px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto" class="LoginForm">
        <table class= "logintable">
             <tr><td width="60%" valign="top">
                  <h3>MySite</h3>
            <h2>Login</h2>
                 <form action="login.php" method="post">
                     <input type="text" name="userlogin" size="12" placeholder="Username"/><br/> <br/>
                <input type="password" name="passwordlogin" size="12" placeholder="Password"/><br/> <br/>
                     <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login!"/>
                     </form>
                 <div id="forgotpassword">
    <a href="#">I forgot my password</a>
    </div>   
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

            </div>
```

The login is the same as earlier (minus the ?user= part). From this I get redirected to the profile page.

profile.php

```
    <?php
session_start();

include './Various/header.php';
require './Various/connections.php';

  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
  $getdata = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
  $firstname = $getdata['firstname'];
  $lastname = $getdata['lastname'];
  $blogname = $getdata['blogname'];
  $shoutout = $getdata['aboutuser'];
  $country = $getdata['country'];
  $profilepic = $getdata['profilephoto'];
  $year = $getdata['yearofbirth'];
  $current = date('Y');
  $age = $current - $year;

?>

<div class="profilepage">
<div class="userdetails">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="<?php echo $profilepic  ?>"/>
</td>

<td>
    <div id="userinfo">
    <h3><?php echo $username?>'s Blog!</h3>
    </div>
<a>Name: <?php echo $firstname?> <?php echo $lastname?>  </a>
<a>Age: <?php  echo $age ?> </a>
<a>Country: <?php echo $country ?> </a>
<a id="shoutout"><?php echo $shoutout ?></a>

</td>

</tr>

</table>
<div id="blogname">
<a><?php echo $blogname ?></a>
</div>
</div>

    <div class="userposts">
    <?php 
  //Displaying user's posts
 //connect to DB
$sql = "SELECT postid, postedby, title, category, LEFT(content, 100) AS content FROM posts WHERE postedby = '$username'
 ORDER BY postid DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $postid = $row['postid'];
    $postedby = $row['postedby'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $content = $row['content'];
    $category = $row['category'];
  ?>
    <div id="posts">
     <a><?php echo $postedby?></a> 
    <h2><?php echo $title?></h2>
        <a><?php echo $category?></a><br>
        <a><?php echo $content . "<a href='post.php?id=$postid'>Read more...</a>"?></a>
        <br>
        <hr />
        <br>

        <?php 
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here I get all the data I want and it's displayed nicely. What I can't seem to do is to allow other users to view this user's profile. I know I need to make a dynamic url variable. One of the tutorial I've followed instructed me to do the following:

```
    if(!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    header("Location: ?user=".getID($_SESSION['id']));
}
```

getID function looks like this:

```
    function getID($id) {
  $dataquery = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id='$id'");  
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($dataquery)){
      return $row['id'];
  }
}
```

When I do the if statement as

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']))
```

All I get is an error in firefox:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>   Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

And this one in Chrome:

> This webpage has a redirect loop

I'm at my wits end and been looking for a solution since Tuesday. I can't move on with my project like this.
I'm sincerely asking for your help. I know it might be much to ask (quite a large chunk of code, eh) but I seriously have no idea what to do with this.

As I mentioned earlier I want to allow users to view other users' profiles. 
I never get the $_GET to work properly so I thought this was the cause. Now I just don't know.

Sorry for a lengthy post and I hope someone can help me out. I really appreciate your help.

Regards

David

Comment: How the URL looks like?

Comment: Post here var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

Comment: Try putting: `ini_set("display_errors", "On"); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of testprofile.php, just to check if it is an error or not. Also make sure you're specifying ?username=...&id=..., since you're echoing both `$_GET['username']` and `$_GET['password']`, meaning they both have to be set or it will error.

Comment: Okay, I tried this and I get Notice: Undefined index: username(...). 
I'm setting the session in login.php though, why do I get that?

Comment: David8 
This is what I got: string(16) "/testprofile.php"

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the spacing in the url.

The `$_GET` array for the url `testprofile.php?username = $loginusername` is:

```
array('username ' => ' $loginusername')
```

As such the key will be `'username '` and not `'username'`. To fix it ensure that there are no unnecessary spaces in your url parameter names and values. Also note that `$_GET['id']` is blank as there is no such parameter being passed in the url.

Comment: Do as @David8 suggested and post the result of `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`